# Facing issue while process the data changes in a file in java

Tags: java, excel

I am facing issue while processing a file data in JAVA program. Even if I have modified the data in a file, it is reflecting the same(old) data which I provided first.

code snippet:

```
public class PMDfileRead {

      private String inputFile;

      public void setInputFile(String inputFile) {
        this.inputFile = inputFile;
      }

      public void read( ) throws Exception  {
        File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);
        Workbook w ;
        try {
          w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
          // Get the first sheet
          Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
          .........
          syso(sheet.Rows());
          syso(sheet.Columns());  
        }

      public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        PMDfileRead test = new PMDfileRead();
        System.out.println("inside Main");
        test.setInputFile("xyz.xls");
        test.read();
      }
}
```

When I check the value of rows and columns in a sheet, it is showing the the count which I first provided to the JAVA program. please help me to fix this issue and also let me know what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputWorkbook);
```

Make your processes and insertion and at the end call.

```
workbook.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("out.xls"));
```

This will write your changes in a new file

By the way I think you need to flush your changes to a new file